# Automatically Convert Unicode string to string in Python on Terminal

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, unicode

Assume I have a

```
>>> text = u'ทดสอบ'  # some text
>>> text
u'\u0e17\u0e14\u0e2a\u0e2d\u0e1a'
>>> print(text)
ทดสอบ
>>>
```

I want to `u'\u0e17\u0e14\u0e2a\u0e2d\u0e1a'` always display in a String format like a `ทดสอบ`.

Is it possible to automatically convert a Unicode string to string in Python on Terminal.

Because of some cases, I don't want to use a command such as `print repr(a).decode("unicode-escape")` every time I want to convert a Unicode string to string.

Comment: what is the question? `print(text)` is the correct way to print a Unicode string. And yes, you should *not* call `repr(text).decode('unicode-escape')` (DON'T DO IT!). Do you understand the difference between an object and its string representation? You should probably defined a custom class with `__str__`, `__repr__`,  methods and play with the instance in the REPL while calling `print`, `str()`, `repr()` functions.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian The problem is I want the Terminal always display a Unicode string without using `print`. Because when I want to know what is the `u'\u0e17\u0e14\u0e2a\u0e2d\u0e1a'`, I don't want to use `print` everytime. Sorry, I'm new in Python

Comment: Use Python 3 that uses a more readable representation for Unicode strings and/or override `sys.displayhook()` to display the text however you like